# CocoaLumberJack 2.0.0 compilation errors with Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

My xCode version is 6.3. Installed CocoaLumberJack with cocoapods using

> pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0'

But I get compile errors like in this screen. 
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the CocoaLumberjack swift_support branch until 2.1.0 is released with official Swift support.

Answer (score 1):

Due to some changes in Swift 1.2 and introducing @noescape your code should look slight different right now to make it work (modified original from https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Classes/CocoaLumberjack.swift):

```
extension DDLogFlag {
    public static func fromLogLevel(logLevel: DDLogLevel) -> DDLogFlag {
        return DDLogFlag(logLevel.rawValue)
    }

    ///returns the log level, or the lowest equivalant.
    public func toLogLevel() -> DDLogLevel {
        if let ourValid = DDLogLevel(rawValue: self.rawValue) {
            return ourValid
        } else {
            let logFlag = self
            if logFlag & .Verbose == .Verbose {
                return .Error
            } else if logFlag & .Debug == .Debug {
                return .Debug
            } else if logFlag & .Info == .Info {
                return .Info
            } else if logFlag & .Warning == .Warning {
                return .Warning
            } else if logFlag & .Error == .Error {
                return .Verbose
            } else {
                return .Off
            }
        }
    }
}

public var defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.Verbose

public func resetDefaultDebugLevel() {
    defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.Verbose
}

public func SwiftLogMacro(isAsynchronous: Bool, level: DDLogLevel, flag flg: DDLogFlag, context: Int = 0, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UInt = __LINE__, tag: AnyObject? = nil, @autoclosure #string: () -> String) {
    if level.rawValue & flg.rawValue != 0 {
        // Tell the DDLogMessage constructor to copy the C strings that get passed to it. Using string interpolation to prevent integer overflow warning when using StaticString.stringValue
        let logMessage = DDLogMessage(message: string(), level: level, flag: flg, context: context, file: "\(file)", function: "\(function)", line: line, tag: tag, options: .CopyFile | .CopyFunction, timestamp: nil)

        DDLog.log(isAsynchronous, message: logMessage)
    }
}

public func DDLogDebug(@autoclosure logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Debug, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText())
}

public func DDLogInfo(@autoclosure logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Info, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText())
}

public func DDLogWarn(@autoclosure logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Warning, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText())
}

public func DDLogVerbose(@autoclosure logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Verbose, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText())
}

public func DDLogError(@autoclosure logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = false) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Error, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText())
}

/// Analogous to the C preprocessor macro THIS_FILE
public func CurrentFileName(fileName: StaticString = __FILE__) -> String {
    // Using string interpolation to prevent integer overflow warning when using StaticString.stringValue
    return "\(fileName)".lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what my code looks like. But still I get the errors.

Comment: @iosDev82
Regarding your image I see that You forgot about '()' after 'logText' parameter in 'DDLogError', 'DDLogDebug' ... functions.

Remove MultiFormatter, it isn't necessary.

'@autoclosure' should be before parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, what I basically did was first ensure that my Pod was updated. Then i opened the swift file wich was included in the framework (i the newest cocoapod, otherwise you need to fetch it from the repo directly) and basically just re-pasted the code into the file. I couldnt see any changes but the compiler stopped complaining.

EDIT: Below is my working file for 2.0.0 and Swift 1.2

```
// Software License Agreement (BSD License)
//
// Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Deusty, LLC
// All rights reserved.
//
// Redistribution and use of this software in source and binary forms,
// with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
// * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
//   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
// * Neither the name of Deusty nor the names of its contributors may be used
//   to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific
//   prior written permission of Deusty, LLC.

import Foundation

extension DDLogFlag {
    public static func fromLogLevel(logLevel: DDLogLevel) -> DDLogFlag {
        return DDLogFlag(logLevel.rawValue)
    }

    ///returns the log level, or the lowest equivalant.
    public func toLogLevel() -> DDLogLevel {
        if let ourValid = DDLogLevel(rawValue: self.rawValue) {
            return ourValid
        } else {
            let logFlag = self
            if logFlag & .Verbose == .Verbose {
                return .Error
            } else if logFlag & .Debug == .Debug {
                return .Debug
            } else if logFlag & .Info == .Info {
                return .Info
            } else if logFlag & .Warning == .Warning {
                return .Warning
            } else if logFlag & .Error == .Error {
                return .Verbose
            } else {
                return .Off
            }
        }
    }
}

public var defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.Verbose

public func resetDefaultDebugLevel() {
    defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.Verbose
}

public func SwiftLogMacro(isAsynchronous: Bool, level: DDLogLevel, flag flg: DDLogFlag, context: Int = 0, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UInt = __LINE__, tag: AnyObject? = nil, @autoclosure(escaping) #string: () -> String) {
    if level.rawValue & flg.rawValue != 0 {
        // Tell the DDLogMessage constructor to copy the C strings that get passed to it. Using string interpolation to prevent integer overflow warning when using StaticString.stringValue
        let logMessage = DDLogMessage(message: string(), level: level, flag: flg, context: context, file: "\(file)", function: "\(function)", line: line, tag: tag, options: .CopyFile | .CopyFunction, timestamp: nil)
        DDLog.log(isAsynchronous, message: logMessage)
    }
}

public func DDLogDebug(@autoclosure(escaping) logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Debug, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText)
}

public func DDLogInfo(@autoclosure(escaping) logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Info, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText)
}

public func DDLogWarn(@autoclosure(escaping) logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Warning, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText)
}

public func DDLogVerbose(@autoclosure(escaping) logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = true) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Verbose, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText)
}

public func DDLogError(@autoclosure(escaping) logText: () -> String, level: DDLogLevel = defaultDebugLevel, file: StaticString = __FILE__, function: StaticString = __FUNCTION__, line: UWord = __LINE__, asynchronous async: Bool = false) {
    SwiftLogMacro(async, level, flag: .Error, file: file, function: function, line: line, string: logText)
}

/// Analogous to the C preprocessor macro THIS_FILE
public func CurrentFileName(fileName: StaticString = __FILE__) -> String {
    // Using string interpolation to prevent integer overflow warning when using StaticString.stringValue
    return "\(fileName)".lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension
}
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't help.